Spring Kafka. MetadataUpdater is trying to update the metadata of a deleted topic
In my application I ran into a problem when Kafka MetadataUpdater tries to get the metadata of a topic that has been manually deleted (using AdminClient).
Because of this, in log I get a lot of messages like [Producer clientId=producer-_] Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 2620 : {deleted_topic_name=UNKNOWN_TOPIC_OR_PARTITION} 
I would like to prevent metadata updates for topic that I have deleted. Any suggestions how can I do this?
I should also note that this problem does not occur every time a topic is deleted. In most cases, when I delete a topic, everything works as I expect, and the metadata does not try to be updated. But in any case, sometimes I run into this problem. I would like to avoid this problem altogether.
PS. I use org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients:3.1.2
The only solution I came to is configure topic auto-creation. But obviously this solution is not appropriate for me, because I want topic to be deleted. I just need to prevent metadata updates without any manipulations with topic creation.

Can you tell us how it may be related to Spring Kafka? It does not look like this happens from Spring Kafka. If there is a way for us to reproduce this issue, we can look into it further, but on the surface, it looks like a Kafka question.
